# javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter execution threw an exception in spring boot

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot

When I implement the hashCode() method in Entity classes, I get the following error. What 's that ?

> javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter execution threw an exception
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:200)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:130)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:66)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:105)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   java.lang.StackOverflowError  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:116)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2212.executeQuery(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:70)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.getResultSet(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:434)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:186)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:121)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:86)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:88)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:688)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:75)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1991)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:570)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:252)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:566)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:135)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.hashCode(PersistentSet.java:430)
>     at java.util.Arrays.hashCode(Arrays.java:4146)  at
>   java.util.Objects.hash(Objects.java:128)  at
>   net.fis.fava.model.Group.hashCode(Group.java:115)     at
>   java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:339)  at
>   java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:612)   at
>   java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:220)   at
>   java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:344)  at
>   org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.endRead(PersistentSet.java:327)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollection(CollectionLoadContext.java:234)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollections(CollectionLoadContext.java:221)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollections(CollectionLoadContext.java:194)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.endLoading(CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.java:154)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.finishLoadingCollections(AbstractRowReader.java:249)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.finishUp(AbstractRowReader.java:212)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractResults(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:133)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:122)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:86)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:88)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:688)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:75)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1991)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:570)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:252)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:566)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:135)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.hashCode(PersistentSet.java:430)
>     at java.util.Arrays.hashCode(Arrays.java:4146)  at
>   java.util.Objects.hash(Objects.java:128)  at
>   net.fis.model.Activity.hashCode(Activity.java:146)    at
>   java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:339)  at
>   java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:612)   at
>   java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:220) . . . . .

Comment: can you provide code for your Entity class?

Comment: Please provide the implementation of the `hashCode` method which you have implemented.

Answer (score 0):

This is also an instance of the Entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TBL_ACTIVITY", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "ROLE", name = "ROLE_UN") })
public class Activity implements Serializable, Comparable<Activity> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2312346871583335007L;

    private Long activityId;

    private String role;
    private String description;

    private Activity parent;

    private Set<Group> groups = new HashSet<>(0);
    private Set<Activity> children = new HashSet<>(0);

    public Activity() {}

    public Activity(String role, String description) {
        this.role = role;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Activity(String role, String description, Activity parent) {
        this.role = role;
        this.description = description;

        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public Activity(String role, String description, Activity parent, Set<Group> groups, Set<Activity> children) {
        this.role = role;
        this.description = description;

        this.parent = parent;

        this.groups = groups;
        this.children = children;
    }

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "FIS_SEQ", sequenceName = "FIS_SEQ")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "FIS_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "ACTIVITY_ID", nullable = false, unique = true, precision = 19)
    public Long getActivityId() {
        return activityId;
    }

    public void setActivityId(Long activityId) {
        this.activityId = activityId;
    }

    @Column(name = "ROLE", nullable = false, length = 100)
    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION", length = 100)
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID")
    public Activity getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(Activity parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "parent")
    public Set<Activity> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public void setChildren(Set<Activity> children) {
        this.children = children;
    }

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH} ,fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "activities")
    public Set<Group> getGroups() {
        return groups;
    }

    public void setGroups(Set<Group> groups) {
        this.groups = groups;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Activity o) {
        return Integer.compare(Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(this.activityId)), Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(o.getActivityId())));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Activity activity = (Activity) o;
        return Objects.equals(activityId, activity.activityId) &&
                Objects.equals(role, activity.role) &&
                Objects.equals(description, activity.description) &&
                Objects.equals(parent, activity.parent) &&
                Objects.equals(groups, activity.groups) &&
                Objects.equals(children, activity.children);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(activityId, role, description, parent, groups, children);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Activity { " +
                "activityId = " + activityId +
                ", role = '" + role + '\'' +
                ", description = '" + description + '\'' +
                ", parent = " + parent +
                ", groups = " + groups +
                ", children = " + children +
                " }";
    }

}
```

Comment: Help me, Please.